# Rails 5 model custom validation with relation has many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, ruby-on-rails-5

In my Rails 5.2 app, I have the following Model relations.
A **`Job`** has many **`Contracts`** and has many **`Expertises`**. Resulting in the following Ruby on Rails models.

### `job.rb`

```rb
class Job < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :attached_expertises, as: :expertisable, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :expertises, through: :attached_expertises
  has_many :attached_contracts, as: :contractable, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :contracts, through: :attached_contracts
end
```

### `contract.rb`

```rb
class Contract < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :attached_contracts, dependent: :destroy
end
```

### `attached_contract.rb`

```rb
class AttachedContract < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :contract
  belongs_to :contractable, polymorphic: true
end
```

### `expertise.rb`

```rb
class Expertise < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :attached_expertises
end
```

### `attached_expertise.rb`

```rb
class AttachedExpertise < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :expertise
  belongs_to :expertisable, polymorphic: true
end
```

I need to perform a validation in Job depending in the values of the associated models.
I have 3 types of **Contracts** and 3 types of **Expertises** as well.
Lets say contracts can be **P, C or E**, and Expertises **J, L, S**.
When creating or updating a **Job** if **Contract** of type **E** is selected, **Expertise** must be of type **J**, otherwise if should raise an error.

I have tried this creating custom validation ActiveModel::EachValidator. But was not able to get it to work. Neither with a custom method in the model it self.

Whats is the best way to achieve this?
And where should I place the validator file? In `app/models/concerns/`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `validates_with` and write a custom method to do the checking

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_with GoodnessValidator
end

class GoodnessValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
 def validate(record)
  if record.first_name == "Evil"
   record.errors[:base] << "This person is evil"
  end
 end
end
```

Comment: I am trying to do that but I get an error `uninitialized constant Job::Contracts`. My validator is in the folder `app/models/concerns/` with a `class Contracts < ActiveModel::Validator`, and in my model I have `include ActiveModel::Validations` and `validates_with Contracts` What I am getting wrong?

Comment: FIXED: It was a naning convention problem the validator file needs to be named `contracts.rb` and it was named `contracts_validator.rb`